# Install several packages in one call to underlying package manager with Chef?

Tags: chef-infra

Package managers are so slow on the uptake ;) I'm using Yum on CentOS and installing each package takes much time.

Is there a way to install several packages in a one call to the underlying package manager in Chef? I can just execute yum or RPM from the recipe, but this is not elegant and not portable also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an option as it doesn't lend itself to clear convergent modelling in the way the `package` resource currently works. You could build a resource for `yum_batch` or similar, but I don't know of one off hand. A possible future extension would be something like chef-metal's `machine_batch` resource wrapper, but I'm not a big fan of that approach.

EDIT: This was added in Chef 12.1.0. You can now do `package ['one', 'two']` in recipe code.